# What Is the Motivation of Proximal Mapping / Proximal Operator?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

For a convex function $h$, its proximal operator is defined as:
$$\operatorname{prox}_h(x)=\arg\min_u \Big(h(u)+\frac{1}{2}\|u-x\|^2\Big)$$
Can anyone provide an intuitive explanation/motivation of proximal mapping?

Comment: Not an answer, but... If you let $g(x) = \frac{1}{2} ||x||^2$, then the function $h \square g (x) = \inf_{u} h(u)+g(x-u)$ is called the infimal convolution and corresponds to the function you get from the set $\mathbb{epi}\, h + \mathbb{epi} \, g$. So there is a nice geometrical interpretation as a 'smoothing' of sorts. Rockafellar's classic Convex Analysis is a good read & reference. Predates the current popularization of convex analysis.

Comment: Oops, I should have been more explicit, $\mathbb{epi} \, h \square g = \mathbb{epi} \,h + \mathbb{epi} \, g$. The epigraph defines the function.

Comment: I also don't have a definite answer, but one way to think of it is that you want a point that minimizes $h(u)$ but is also close to $x$ (the argument of prox). There is usually also a constant that dictates the tradeoff between these two components of the objective. The prox operator is very important in convex analysis and its properties are well studied. Take a look at [this monograph](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/prox_algs.pdf) by Boyd for more details.

Answer (score 10):

Here are two interpretations which can lend useful intuition in some circumstances:

**Prox is a generalized projection**

Consider the indicator of some nonempty convex set $X$: $$i_X(x) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{if } x \in X \\ \infty & \text{if } x \not \in X\end{cases}.$$ Then we find that the proximal mapping is the projection onto $X$: $$\begin{align}\text{prox}_{\alpha i_X}(y) &= \underset{x}{\text{argmin}}(\alpha i_X(x)+\frac{1}{2}\|x - y\|^2) \\ &= \underset{x \in X}{\text{argmin}}(\frac{1}{2}\|x - y\|^2) \\ &= \text{proj}_X(y).\end{align}$$

**Prox is backward Euler**

Consider the backward Euler update: $x^{k+1} = x^k - \alpha \nabla f(x^{k+1})$ for some differentiable $f$. This update can be viewed as a proximal point update $x^{k+1} = \text{prox}_{\alpha f}(x^k)$, since for differentiable convex functions the optimality condition is $0 = \nabla (\alpha f(x^\star) + \frac{1}{2}\|x^\star - x^k\|^2) = \alpha \nabla f(x^\star) + x^\star - x^k$.

Answer (score 7):

If $h$ is a closed convex function, then the proximal operator of $h$ (with parameter $t > 0$) is defined by
$$
\text{prox}_{th}(\hat x) = \arg \min_x \, h(x) + \frac{1}{2t} \|x - \hat x \|_2^2.
$$
When we evaluate the prox-operator of $h$, we are attempting to reduce the value of $h$, but we are penalized for straying too far from $\hat x$. (The parameter $t$ is like a "step size" that controls how much we are penalized for moving away from $\hat x$.)

You can see that evaluating a prox-operator might be a useful sub-step in an optimization algorithm. For example, suppose that we want to solve the optimization problem
$$
\text{minimize} \quad g(x) + h(x)
$$
where $g$ and $h$ are convex, $g$ is differentiable, and $h$ is "simple" in the sense that its prox-operator can be evaluated efficiently. (Importantly, $h$ is *not* required to be differentiable.) A natural strategy is to first reduce the value of $g$ by taking a step in the negative gradient direction, then reduce the value of $h$ by applying the prox-operator of $h$, and repeat. This strategy yields the following iteration:
$$
x^{k+1} = \text{prox}_{th}(x^k - t \nabla g(x^k)).
$$
(This iteration is known as the proximal gradient method. You could implement it right now in Python to solve famous optimization problems such as the Lasso problem from statistics.)

---

Here is an alternative way to derive the proximal gradient method and, in the process, discover the proximal operator. Suppose again that we want to minimize $g(x) + h(x)$, with $g$ and $h$ as given above. A natural strategy is to replace $g$ with a local linear approximation to $g$ (this is the fundamental strategy of calculus), and also to add a penalty term to the objective function which penalizes us from straying too far from the current iterate (this ensures that the local linear approximation to $g$ remains accurate). This strategy yields the following iteration:
$$
x^{k+1} = \arg \min_x \quad h(x) + \underbrace{g(x^k) + \nabla g(x^k)^T(x - x^k)}_{\approx \, g(x)} + \frac{1}{2t} \|x - x^k \|_2^2.
$$
Now if we combine the two terms on the right by **completing the square**, and then omit terms that do not depend on $x$, we find that
\begin{align}
x^{k+1} &= \arg \min_x \, h(x) + \frac{1}{2t} \|x - (x^k - t\nabla g(x^k)) \|_2^2 \\
&= \text{prox}_{th}(x^k - t\nabla g(x^k)).
\end{align}
This is the proximal gradient iteration. We see that the proximal operator of $h$ has appeared out of thin air. To me this seems like the most likely way that someone would discover the idea of a proximal operator.

---

Another motivation for the proximal operator comes from the viewpoint of monotone operator theory. Minimizing a closed convex function $h$ is equivalent to finding a point $x$ such that
$$ 
\tag{1} 0 \in \partial h(x).
$$
Here $\partial h(x)$ is the subdifferential of $h$ at $x$. The set-valued mapping $x \mapsto \partial h(x)$ is the best example of a "monotone operator", and problem (1) is called a "monotone inclusion problem". Multiplying both sides by $t$ and then adding $x$ to both sides, we find that
\begin{align}
& 0 \in \partial h(x) \\
\iff & x \in (I + t \partial h)(x) \\
\iff & x \in (I + t \partial h)^{-1}(x).
\end{align}
The operator $(I + t \partial h)^{-1}$ is called the "resolvent" of the operator $\partial h$, and it has nice properties such as the following: if $x \in \mathbb R^n$, then $(I + t \partial h)^{-1}(x)$ is a singleton. Thus, $(I + t \partial h)^{-1}$ can be viewed as a *function* (rather than a set-valued mapping), and solving $0 \in \partial h(x)$ is equivalent to solving

$$
x = (I + t \partial h)^{-1}(x).
$$
A natural idea is to solve for $x$ using fixed point iteration. The resulting iteration is
$$
x^{k+1} = (I + t \partial h)^{-1}(x^k).
$$

*Punch line:* The function $(I + t \partial h)^{-1}$ is none other than the proximal operator of $h$, and this iteration is known as the "proximal point algorithm".

Comment: In the second line after the second $0 \in \partial h(x)$: shouldn't it be $x= (I+t\partial h)^{-1}(x)$ instead of $x\in (I+t\partial h)^{-1}(x)$?

Comment: @Broken_Window My thought process: at that point in my exposition, it wasn't clear that $(I + t \partial h)^{-1}$ can be viewed as a function rather than as a set-valued mapping (because usually the inverse of a set-valued mapping is a set-valued mapping).  So I wrote $x \in (I + t \partial h)^{-1}(x)$. But then we note that one of the nice properties of this resolvent operator that we have stumbled upon is that $(I + t \partial h)^{-1}(x)$ is a singleton. Thus, at that point, we rewrite the previous equation as $x = (I + t \partial h)^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I went confused because some books make the expression $(I+t\partial h)^{-1}x$ equal to the proximal map of $h(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

There are many good answers here already, but for the sake of completeness I will add on more intuition. The proximal operator of $g$ (with parameter $\lambda$) can also be seen as a gradient step (with stepsize $\lambda$) with respect to the Moreau envelope $g_\lambda$ of $g$. The Moreau envelope is a smooth under approximation of the original function and is given by
$$
g_\lambda(x) = \min_u \{g(u) + \frac{1}{2 \lambda} || u-x||^2\}. 
$$
Evidently its definition is closely related to the proximal operator. The above mentioned identity then reads as
$$
\operatorname{prox}_{\lambda g}(x) = x - \lambda \nabla g_\lambda(x).
$$