# Different definitions of the proximal map? What is going on here

Tags: optimization, proximal-operators

I am really confused about the proximal operator. My teacher has lectured and posted notes where she defines the proximal operator like this:

[image]

I am trying to get some intuition for this weird function. What is the variable $\xi$ supposed to represent? I know there is some notion where this is supposed to generalize projection?

So naturally I try to look up some other resources. But when I look up the proximal mapping on the internet people have a different definition. For example here:

[What Is the Motivation of Proximal Mapping / Proximal Operator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168159/what-is-the-motivation-of-proximal-mapping-proximal-operator)

Are these definitions somehow the same? Can someone help me out of this mess?